# The transform of a Hermitian matrix by a unitary matrix is Hermitian

Tags: linear-algebra

In the [following document](http://sylvester.math.nthu.edu.tw/d2/ams/wedderburn/coll17-chvi.pdf),  p91 (or p4 of the PDF) , section 6.03, it is stated that "**The transform of a hermitian matrix by a unitary matrix is hermitian**." Apparently the proof is obvious, but not to me... could someone elaborate?

Comment: What is the transform of a matrix by another?

Comment: I guess it means the product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A matrix is hermitian if $ A^\ast = A$ where $A^\ast$ is the conjugated and transposed of $A$. 
Unitary matrices have the property that $U\cdot U^\ast= Id$ where Id is the identity. So in special we have $U^\ast =U^{-1}$.

Now we look at the transformed hermitian: 
$$ U^{-1} A U=U^\ast A U$$ 
if conjugate and transpose this we have 
$$ (U^\ast A U)^\ast = U^\ast A^\ast (U^\ast)^\ast= U^\ast A^\ast U=U^\ast A U$$
which says that the transformed still hermitian.